# Autocomplete Fields in Split Database

Tags: ms-access, autocomplete

I created a data entry from and split my database to front-end and back-end. When I enter in data I want certain fields to autocomplete. To be specific, I want to do something like (assuming the term Request had been previously entered) when you type in Requ... it would show Request and you could just press enter or tab to move to the next field. I don't want the rest of the fields autofilled, just individual fields autocompleted. Not sure if the fact that the database is split prohibits this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a form, set the controls for the fields you want to autocomplete to comboboxes and the row source of the combo to a select from the table:

```
 Control Source : MyFieldToComplete 
 Row Source : SELECT DISTINCT MyFieldToComplete FROM MyTableWithMyField
 Limit To List : No
```

There are wizards for building combos, or you can change controls manually with right-click.

[image]

Comment: No, if you click on `...` it will bring you to the builder where you can select your table and field, otherwise, just type the sql into the little box.